# Too many open files in AWK

Tags: bash, awk, gzip

I'm stuck in a problem and I hope someone can help me.

I need to read a big log file that is gzipped, and for each line read, get a certain field and create or append the entire line to this file (gzipped), depending on the value of this field.

Initially I wasn't creating or appending the line to a gzipped file but I really don't have enough space on server, so, I need to do in this way.

Because of the use of the gzip in AWK, with the use of pipe and quotes, the ending part (close file) stopped work.

I tried to move this close file to the beginning of the AWK but I keep getting this (Too many open files message.

Before using the gzip in the middle the AWK everything is was working.

**Works but doesn't append to a gzipped file:**

```
for _csv in $( ls ${_in_path}${_letter}_*_*.csv.gz ); do
    zcat $_csv | sort -t',' -T tmp -k4 | awk -F "," '{ _key = $4; _fn = "requests_by_IP/"_key".csv"; printf "%s\n", $0 >> _fn; close(_fn)}'
done
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
for _csv in $( ls ${_in_path}${_letter}_*_*.csv.gz ); do
    zcat $_csv | sort -t',' -T tmp -k4 | awk -F "," '{ if (!_fn) { close(_fn); } _key = $4; _fn = "requests_by_IP/"_key".csv.gz"; printf "%s\n", $0 | "gzip >> "_fn;}'
done
```

```
for _csv in $( ls ${_in_path}${_letter}_*_*.csv.gz ); do
    zcat $_csv | sort -t',' -T tmp -k4 | awk -F "," ' _key = $4; _fn = "requests_by_IP/"_key".csv.gz"; printf "%s\n", $0 | "gzip >> "_fn; close(_fn);}'
done
```

Note: If i don't use the gzip command inside quotes ("gzip >> ") I get this generic **syntax error at or near >** error

Edit: Thanks a lot @edmorton! Especially by the https://www.shellcheck.net/ tip !!!

Comment: Can you use GNU awk? It automatically closes files as needed to avoid running out of descriptors.

Comment: @Barmar though that's true, the right approach in this case is to sort the input by the key value first (as the OP is doing) and so you only need 1 output pipe open at a time so throwing in a single `close()` when the key changes before determining the new output string is trivial and would help with a gawk solution too since gawk slows down once it's managing too many open files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To awk the output is a pipe to `"gzip >> "_fn`, not the file whose name is stored in `_fn`, so **that** is what you need to close, e.g. `close("gzip >> "_fn)`. You should copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about first though as you have some quoting and other issues outside of the awk script.

Anyway, it seems like this might be what you're trying to do (untested):

```
for csv in "${_in_path}${_letter}_"*_*'.csv.gz'; do
    zcat "$csv" |
    sort -t',' -T tmp -k4 |
    awk -F ',' '
        $4 != key {
            close(out)
            key = $4
            fn  = "requests_by_IP/" key ".csv.gz"
            out = "gzip >> " fn
        }
        { print | out }
    '
done
```

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is select the $ 4 element (which corresponds to an IP in the log) and throw the entire log line in a file that will only contain requests made by that particular IP. My source files have requests / lines that correspond to several different IPs.

In fact what I need is to group requests by the IP that made them, without being able to use a db and without having practically available space.

So my key will always be the $ 4 element, and I just need to append the current line to a file with the same name as my key.

Comment: That's what I thought so that's what my script does. Did you try it?